# How To Post Angular 4 Form JSON Data to Firebase?

Tags: json, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make an Angular 4 form, and I want to hit send and have the JSON data go from the form to the firebase backend. I know how to get the JSON Data to show up, I just have no idea how to post it and save it. Could someone send me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of Angular form structure are you using? Are you working with form builder to create the form? If so you can run `this.theFormName.values` and that will return the forms values and post that straight to firebase. If you're using another method you might need to manually build the json object.

Comment: FWIW, the angularfire project: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 makes it pretty easy to work with Firebase from Angular.

Comment: So say I use regular html input and use form builder to create the form and I used .value to get the json data. Now how can I send this data to the database.